# Loopback query with where inside include

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I am trying to query my data the following way:

```
const filter = {where: {activity_id: activity_id, include: {relation: 'planGoal', scope: {where: {activity_goal_id: goal_id}}}}};
```

However this doesn't seem to work only the `activity_id` filter is applied and the wrong data is returned.

So my question is how do I query data within an include? and is it even possible?

For reference, here are the models in question:

```
    {
  "name": "plan_goal_has_action_option",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "activity_id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "plan_has_goal_id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "action_option": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "planGoal": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "plan_has_goal",
      "foreignKey": "plan_has_goal_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}


    {
  "name": "plan_has_goal",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "activity_id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "activity_goal_id": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "goal": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "activity_goal",
      "foreignKey": "activity_goal_id"
    },
    "actions": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "plan_goal_has_action_option",
      "foreignKey": "plan_has_goal_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include` and `where` are two different filters:

```js
{  
  where: {
    activity_id: activity_id
  },
  include: {  
    relation: 'planGoal',
    scope: {
      where: {
        activity_goal_id: goal_id
      }
    }
  }
}
```